# How can I bach export videos, using the audio length in Powerpoint w/ VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

*I'm no VBA dev, and I'm struggling to achieve what I aim to do.*

**I'm trying to get each slide in the powerpoint documents I'm making, to be exported separately from the rest, using the length of the audio present in each slide.**

For example, I've got a project with 55 slides, and each slide contains a voice-over with linked animations. I want to export those 55 slides separately with the exact voice-over length.

I tried that by doing this code here :

```
Sub ExportVideoV1()

' Variables '
Dim SL As Slide, Sh As Shape

Dim audioName As String, audioLength As Single


With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties

    ' Hide all document's slides '
    For i = 1 To .Count
        For Each SL In ActivePresentation.Slides
            allDocumentsSlides.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
        Next
    Next

    ' For each slide, unhide it, check audio length, export then hide back '
    For i = 1 To allDocumentsSlides
    
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Hidden = msoFalse
    
        audioName = "slide-" & i
        audioLength = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(audioName).MediaFormat.Length
        
        Presentation.CreateVideo FileName:=audioName & ".mp4", _
                                      VertResolution:=1080, _
                                      FramesPerSecond:=25, _
                                      Quality:=100
        
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Hidden = msoTrue
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting errors but I don't quite understand why.
If someone could help me by pointing out the errors or what I should be doing instead or give me ressources, I would gladly appreciate.

Comment: What error messages are you getting and on which specific lines, please?